# Can temporary visitors be married in the US?

Tags: united-states, marriage

Suppose there are two individuals from country A. Both have single nationalities (A) and neither of them is a PR or citizen of USA. Suppose that they are on student/visitor visas. Assuming that the marriage is legal in A, can they legally be married in the US (for instance, in Vegas) with no prior permission from country A?

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether the marriage is legal in A, you can get married in the US. No permission from A is required. If Las Vegas is where you want to do it, here is what you need to know:

> Requirements
>
> Neither blood tests nor waiting periods are required if you want to
>   tie the knot. The legal age is 18 for both men and women (proof of age
>   is required) and licensing fees are $77. Civil ceremonies can be
>   performed at the Marriage Commissioner's Office at 309 S. 3rd St.
>   Chapel fees vary depending on the services provided.
>
> Marriage License
>
> For marriage license information visit the Clark County Marriage
>   License Bureau or call (702) 671-0600), 201 Clark Avenue (located on
>   the northwest corner of Clark Avenue and Third Street). Marriage
>   License Bureau hours are 8 a.m. to midnight, including holidays.
>
> **You can get married in Vegas even if you're not a U.S. resident**. Most
>   countries require a certified copy of your marriage certificate ($15)
>   and an apostille from the Nevada Secretary of State ($20). Contact
>   home country's Consulate office located in the U.S., to inquire if
>   additional certifications are required.

http://www.lasvegas.com/planning-tools/weddings/online-marriage-pre-app/

When you return to A, your marriage may not be legally binding, according to the laws of A, but that has no bearing on your ability to get married in the US.

Comment: Actually, each state makes its own rules about who can marry in that state, and what requirements they must meet.  States may also delegate some of this authority to local jurisdictions.  Before planning to marry in the US, a couple should investigate the requirements and procedures of the jurisdiction in which they hope to wed.

Comment: @phoog States and local jurisdictions impose their own requirements for legal age, waiting periods, residency periods, blood tests, etc., but no state bars temporary visitors (legal and illegal) to the US from getting married.